# Rails: Undefined method error on authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create an authentication system on RAILS with `find_by_user_name_and_password()`

I have the following problem:

```
undefined method `find_by_user_name_and_password' for #<Class:0x007fae373d5698>
Rails.root: /ror/blog/Blog`

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

Here is my code from sessions_controller

```
    class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_filter :authorizes
  def new
  end

  def create
        user = User.find_by_user_name_and_password(params[:name], params[:password]) 
        if user
            session[:user_id] = user.id
            redirect_to admin_url
        else
            redirect_to login_url, alert: "Bad datas"
        end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    rederect_to blog_url, notice: "End seans"
  end
end
```

model defenition:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :password_digest, :password_confirmation
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    #validates_confirmation_of :password  
  has_secure_password
end
```

Migrate

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is your database column `user_name` or `username`?

Comment: Try `User.find_by_username_and_password`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your model that you just posted, I see you don't have a password field... so no `find_by_whatever_and_password`.

You need to use

```
user = User.find_by_name(params[:user][:name])
if user && user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
  # etc.
```

Comment: Give us your model definition

Comment: if i am trying like this:
`user = User.find_by_name(params[:name])
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])`
i have this error :
invalid hash

Comment: So give us you view file. Please be more detailed when asking something on SO. It's not to us to ask you for informations ;)

Comment: `<div class="depot_form">
 <% if flash[:alert] %>
  <p id="notice"><%= flash[:alert] %> </p>
 <% end %>
 
 <%= form_tag do %>
  <fieldset>
   <legend> Please, do registration </legend>
   
   <div>
    <%= label_tag :name, 'Name' %>
    <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name] %>
   </div>
   
   <div>
    <%= label_tag :password, 'Password' %>
    <%= password_field_tag :password, params[:password] %>
   </div>
   <div>
    <%= submit_tag "Login" %>
   </div>
  </fieldset>
 <% end %>
</div>`